# How do I get the referrer's domain/host name using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know I can get the host name of the current page, by simply doing:

```
var myhostname = location.hostname;
```

But how do I get the host name of the referrer? I can get the referrer by

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

but unfortunately there's no `document.referrer.hostname` available in JavaScript. How can I get this value?

An example of where this is useful is if somebody clicks a link on google.com. I want to be able to retrieve google.com from the referrer (not the page and the query string).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By parsing it.  `document.referrer.split( '/' );` will get you close.  Or take a look at this

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

If referrer is coming from a browser, it will be sane -- but just in case you want more robust parsing.

Comment: If you don't want to re-invent the parsing wheel: with `var a = document.createElement('a')` create an anchor element, then set `a.href = document.referrer` and then simply read out `a.hostname.` Or, even simpler (if you are using NPM), use [ulocation](https://npmjs.com/package/ulocation): `npm install -S ulocation`, `var Location = require('ulocation')` and use `Location(document.referrer).hostname`. *Disclaimer: I am the author of that package*

Answer (score 58):

This would do:

```
document.referrer.split('/')[2];
```

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/V746B/)

Comment: splitting on the / did not work for me. i had to split on the comma for some reason. it works, but not sure if this might be because of changes since 2010.

Comment: To remove port you can use `document.referrer.split('/')[2].split(':')[0];`

Answer (score 42):

```
function parseURL(url) {
    var a=document.createElement('a');
    a.href=url;
    return a.hostname;
}
```

This is a relatively old question, nevertheless this may help any followers.

Comment: beautiful use of inbuilt browser capabilities

Comment: need to test that url is not empty as it will be treated as relative to the current page (that is in the question if there is no referrer)

Answer (score 16):

You can use `var referrer = new URL(document.referrer).hostname`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.URL.

Comment: Very clean but be aware it's not currently supported in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.URL#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp to extract this data.

`string.match(/^http([s]?)://([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)(:[0-9]+)?/);`

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this function to get domain name.

```
function getDomain(url) {
    if (url) {
        var match = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+:\/)?[^:?#\/\s]*?([^.\s]+\.(?:[a-z]{2,}|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|org\.au|com\.au))(?:[:?#\/]|$)/gi
                .exec(url);
        return match ? match[1] : null;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It includes the protocol, but `document.origin` will work. It works via the Origin header, which has no path information included with it.