# Detect if user is directed from you website

Tags: javascript, php

I want to play an animation when you are not redirected from my page (when you have not clicked a link on `My` page and got redirected to another page on `My` page) much like: [animade.tv](http://animade.tv)

It there any way to detect that with javascript? If not, can you do it with php?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "redirected?"

Comment: Pick which one you want and then google it. There are so many examples. [Here is a PHP one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313834/how-to-detect-the-site-a-user-came-from-before-mine-in-php), and [Here is a JS one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420031/how-do-i-get-the-referrers-domain-host-name-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both `js` or `php`

js:
`document.referrer`

php:
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

sometimes it could be empty, you can just verify that is different from your domain

Comment: PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can't be relied on. Here's why http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Comment: that's why i said that it could be empty, but is it's empty because not provided, you surely know that he's not coming from your website

Answer (score 1):

use `document.referrer` to test the url